# ReactJS Cordova Router issue

Tags: android, reactjs, cordova, react-router-v4

I am creating a simple app with ReactJS and Cordova. The app works fine when I run it through reacts npm start. However when I do a npm run build and copy the build folder into the www folder of my cordova project, I get a blank screen when I run it in android. If I do a cordova run browser the router is not working and its landing at index.html. I think I have narrowed it down to a router issue with `cordova` where route is not setting the page to home. Has anyone else had an issue like this? I created my `reactJS` project using npm create-react-app.

https://github.com/bscott8605/reactRouterTest

Folder Structure

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router'
import Home from './Home'
import AddNote from './AddNote'
import Note from './Note'

class Main extends Component {    
    render() {
      let notes;

      if(this.props.notesList)
      {
          //console.log(this.props);
          notes = this.props.notesList.map(note => {
              return(
                  <Note key={note.title} note={note} />
              );
          });
      }
      return (
          <Router>
        <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
                    <Route path='/AddNote' component={AddNote}/>
                    {/*<Route exact path='/' render={(props) => (<Home {...props} data={notes}/>)}/>
                    <Route exact path='/AddNote' render={(props) => (<AddNote {...props} addNoteMethod={this.props.addNoteMethod}/>)}/>*/}
                </Switch>
        </div>
       </Router>
      );
    }
  }

  export default Main;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change BrowserRouter to Router

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import createHistory from 'history/createHashHistory'

import store from './app/redux/store';
import Layout from './app/pages/layout';
import Routes from './app/pages/routes';

import './app/assets/favicon.ico';
import './app/assets/scss/main.scss';

const history = createHistory();
console.log(history);
const Dom = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Layout>
        <Routes />
      </Layout>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  Dom,
  document.getElementById('app'),
);
```